# "It is the category where most of the processed data falls into" - is it correct?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Is the following sentence correct? I have some doubts about "category where ... fall into" phrase.

> It is the category where most of the processed data falls into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of a preposition with *where* is non-Standard, because *where* itself stands for a preposition phrase. It's equivalent to *in which* or *from which* or *at which* or . . . which specific preposition is involved is inferred from the context. But the preposition is built in to the term *where*.

So if you're using your example in a context where Standard English is called for, you may say "the category ***where*** most of the processed data falls <s>into</s>" or "the category ***which*** most of the processed data falls ***into***", but not "the category ***where*** most of the processed data falls ***into***".

BUT: In some cases an extra preposition is necessary and acceptable. In particular, because *where* "defaults" to designating a location or a goal, adding *from* to designate an origin will often be necessary: "From where did you come?" (or "Where did you come from?"). Note, however, that this will not be necessary with a verb like *get*, which inherently implies an origin.

AND: It must also be acknowledged that in colloquial contexts it is not at all uncommon for a specific preposition to be added to make the specific meaning more explicit; and in these contexts it cannot be regarded as 'incorrect' or 'ungrammatical'.

Note, however, that such an 'extra' preposition is almost always stranded at the end of the clause; you will very rarely see it pied-piped to the position before *where*:

> **<sup>always OK</sup>** the category into which most of the processed data falls
>           **<sup>usually OK</sup>** the category which most of the processed data falls into
>   **<sup>colloquially OK</sup>** the category where most of the processed data falls into
>                  **<sup>not OK</sup>** the category into where most of the processed data falls

Comment: Is the following sentence more formal than the one from my question?
"It is the category (into which / where) most of the X can be classified."

Comment: *Be classified* is not noticeably more 'formal' than *fall* in this context.