# Give this statement "I go to school" --> how to form a question: "where do you go?" or "where do you go to?"

Tags: word-usage

Give this statement "**I go to school**", then how to form a question: "**where do you go?**" or "**where do you go to?**"

I am not sure if we should leave the preposition "**to**" in the question.

Googling "where do you go?" or "where do you go to?", both return the results, so I think they could be used interchangeably. But I am so not sure!

Comment: Look closer at the results. I don't think you can find many (if at all) of `"Where do you go to"` with a question mark right after it. ;-)

Comment: @DamkerngT., what about "Where Do You Go To My Lovely?" Song

Comment: Good find. According to Wikipedia, "Peter Eardley Sarstedt (born 10 December 1941) is an Northern Indian-born British singer-songwriter ...". I'm not sure if that influenced his word choice or maybe it was just for the rhyme. In any case, I don't think it's absolutely wrong, but I'd expect it to be very, very rare.

Comment: [This](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/86680/3463) might help, especially the usage note mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples,

> "Where do you go?"

is correct. There is no need to include the preposition "to." This is also true of the common regional American English phrase,

> X"Where are you at?"

in which the preposition "at" is equally unnecessary.

> "Where are you?"

is both sufficient and generally accepted usage.